# Vue.js How detect if component/page have complete all async calls ??

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, prerender, server-side-rendering

i have question there is some way, how to detect if page was rendered.
I mean after all async calls. Is there some method `isfinalyrendered` ??

Thx

Comment: No, there isn't

Comment: @MatthiasS maybe something in future ??

Comment: I don't see how this would directly correlate to vue.js. What async calls do you mean exactly? The only way I could think of right now is that you use your own ajax wrapper function and reset a timer each time it is called and once that timer ends you call your isFinallyRendered function. Maybe somebody else has a better idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have a logic to `count` the number of `async calls` in your component. As due to particular condition they might be more in one case and lesser in another case.

Then you just have to pass a callback in your async function, which increases the counter on promise `resolve/reject`. When counter's `value==totalAsyncCalls`.
Then you can call your `isfinalyrendered` method

```
var count = totalAsyncCalls
    callback = function () {
        count--;
        if (0==count){
          isfinalyrendered();
         }

        // do stuff
    };
```